# Manjaro Linux won't connect to certain website while other devices do

Tags: linux, manjaro

My Manjaro Linux is not able to connect to my own website on a shared server, while some VirtualBoxes I run on my machine do. I get a 'connection refused' error in Firefox & Chrome as well via FTP.

My iPhone, using the same IP as my Linux laptop (since its in the same WiFi network), connects as well as another laptop I tried. So I think it is not a firewall related problem on the server side of things.

Which configuration could have gone wrong / where should I start to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The host name of laptop has been the same as the domain I wanted to reach. This resulted in the conflict described above.

After changing the hostname and editing /etc/hosts accordingly everything runs fine.